# SwiftUI: Centering a subview of a VStack in the main view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-layout

I want to center a `TextField`, which is in a `VStack`, to the center of the main view / screen. I tried everything I could think of. But no matter what I do SwiftUI is centering the whole `VStack` and not the one `TextField` to the center.
Maybe one of you know how to save my day. Thanks is advance.
Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    // MARK: - Private Properties
    
    @State private var input: String = ""
    
    @State private var inputs: [String] = []
    
    // MARK: - Body
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            content()
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            
            saveButton()
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.brown)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Views
    
    private func content() -> some View {
        VStack {
            textField()
            subtitle()
            entries()
        }
        .padding(10)
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
    
    private func textField() -> some View {
        TextField("TextField", text: $input)
            .font(Font.largeTitle)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .background(Color.red)
    }
    
    private func subtitle() -> some View {
        Text("Text")
            .background(Color.white)
    }
    
    private func entries() -> some View {
        ForEach(inputs, id: \.self) {
            Text($0)
        }
        .background(Color.purple)
    }
    
    private func saveButton() -> some View {
            Button(action: { inputs.append(input); input = "" },
                   label: { Text("Save") })
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Maybe it was not clear. But I want to center the `TextField` **vertically** in the main view.

Answer (score 0):

A hack I use sometimes to centre things when nothing else is working :)

```
VStack {
    Spacer()
    your_view()
    Spacer()
}
```

See if this works for you

```
private func textField() -> some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        TextField("TextField", text: $input)
            .font(Font.largeTitle)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .background(Color.red)
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: No. I want to have the `TextField` centered **vertically** in the main view.

Comment: @NickSorge I have modified the answer for vertical centring. The logic remains pretty much the same